# Getting Uncompressed Size of Raster using ArcObjects?

Tags: raster, arcobjects

How can we get the Uncompressed Size of a raster as shown in the layer properties below using ArcObjects?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean just `columns * rows * bands * pixel_depth / 8`?

Comment: That's all it is. ( Rows x Columns * Bits * band_count ) / 8 to put it into bytes - add some for the header but if you look closely that *Uncompresses Size* listed there does not include header allowance (most noticeable on small rasters as the header is a greater % of the total file size). This is true for any uncompressed BINARY format, text and other formats would be much bigger. If you're really interested, images with less than 8 bits must make whole words (32bits) for each row so that may not be exactly correct for images with less than a byte-per-pixel.

Comment: to downvoter - is it really that bad a question?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - thank you..that gives me a value close to this..but how to get this exact value? Does arcobjects expose it through any interface?

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000wt000000

Comment: Each format has it's own header size but that should be fairly standard if they are created with the same software. The only way I know is to have a test raster (preferably small) convert one of each of the likely formats and subtract the pixel data (formula given) from the actual file size then put the sizes into an enum or table for reference. In the end the only way to get the exact size is to understand each format on a binary level and use that to decide how big the header will be... most don't bother and just use raw pixels as the difference is minor on GIS sized rasters.

Comment: I don't see importance of this question (considered bounty was added). Why should Uncompressed Size of a raster be of interest to people?

Comment: @r.pankevicius - well.. I too do not think it would be of much interest to many people. But definitely I am interested in getting an answer and so the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

For file based rasters, have a look at the [IDatasetFileStat2](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IDatasetFileStat2.htm) interface. It appears that the RasterDataset CoClass implements this interface. So you would need a reference to [IRasterDataset3](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRasterDataset3_Interface/0025000006qw000000/) interface first, then you could cast that information into IDatasetFileStat2 and store it into a variable.

I don't see an SDE equivalent so that method *might* work on SDE as well. The only source that the documentation guarantees it won't work with is personal geodatabases. But who uses those to store rasters in anyway?

There is fairly good documentation on how to get a reference to the IRasterDataset interface [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000021z000000).

Comment: There really is no way to tell the storage requirement in an ArcSDE raster, since the database may have additional overhead (e.g. extent size, high water mark, pages marked as deleted but not yet reused, et. al.).